# NSUserDefaults failing to persist across app shutdown/startup

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

EDIT: Code updated to reflect Paul.s's suggestions.

Have been scouring SO for the past week and still cannot get my app to persist the changes to settings from within the app across a shutdown/restart of the app in both Sim and Device.

Trying to use a NSMutableDictionary from a Singleton, but I don't think this is the problem.

a) Set initial default values for the app using registerDefaults in AppDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
AppManager *global = [AppManager sharedInstance];


// set up the defaults.
global.gWantFoo = YES;    // This is a BOOL which relates to a UISwitch

// #define kWantFoo @"gWantFoo"
global.globalSettingsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                               initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                               [NSNumber numberWithBool:global.gWantFoo], kWantFoo, nil];

global.globalSettings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[global.globalSettings registerDefaults:global.globalSettingsDict];
[global.globalSettings synchronize];
```

b) In the ConfigView where I am able to set the switch, I have the a selector execute the following on a switch change.

```
self.global.gWantFoo = NOT(self.global.gWantFoo);   // #define NOT(a)  !(a)
[self.global.globalSettings setBool:self.global.gWantFoo forKey:kWantFoo];
[self.global.globalSettings synchronize];
```

c) I have a synchronize in applicationDidEnterBackground and friends, and while the switch value does keep the change for the duration of the app instance's life, once I restart,    gWantFoo    is overwritten with the default of "YES".

Any advice is appreciated.  I'm on the verge of defenestrating my ailing macbook pro with a hail of expletives following it closely behind.  Ok, i'm calmer for this edit.  I feel like gently shaking the macbook pro to demonstrate that i'm less than pleased with NSUserDefaults :-)

Cheers

sc.

Comment: You say you use `registerDefaults:` - are you by any chance settings a default value for `gSettingsAreSet` if so this will never return `nil` for `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"gSettingsAreSet"];` Also why is this a string? It seems like the perfect use case for a boolean...

Comment: Hi Paul, yep also setting default value for that. I agree that it should be a BOOL; a remnant from some earlier debugging/cargo cult attempt.  I switched to using a BOOL but to no avail.  I think I need to rip this all out and start over. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I think you should just stick with `registerDefaults:` as it does what I think you are trying to do. It won't wipe saved info from the `NSUserDefaults` only provide values when nothing has been set yet...

Comment: Hi Paul, have ripped out and gone with just registerDefaults. No luck i'm afraid.  I believe my problem stems from actually updating the values - i.e, somehow i'm using this wrong ->  setBool:global.gWantFoo forKey:@"gWantFoo"

Answer (score 3):

So from start to finish this is what you need to do/what should be happening

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` one of the first things you do is register defaults like this:

```
NSDictionary *defaultsDefaults = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] , PSWantFoo, nil];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults registerDefaults:defaultsDefaults];
```

Note: `PSWantFoo` is defined as `NSString * const PSWantFoo = @"PSWantFoo";` so i don't have string literals littered everywhere.

At this point if the app has never been run `NSLog(@"%d", [defaults boolForKey:PSWantFoo]);` it will print `0`.

Now when I want to set the value I use something like:

```
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:PSWantFoo];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Now when I run `NSLog(@"%d", [defaults boolForKey:PSWantFoo]);` it will print `1`.

As for persistance at this point as I have actually set a value a plist is created for me at

```
<path to app>/Library/Preferences/<bundle identifier>.plist
```

If you inspect this file you will see something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PSWantFoo</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now from this point on this value will be read as opposed to the one registered in `registerDefaults:`

---

Update

Why have you hardcoded this in this order?

```
// set up the defaults.
global.gWantFoo = YES;    // This is a BOOL which relates to a UISwitch
```

Why not do it the other way round?

Register defaults with default value YES;

```
NSDictionary *defaultsDefaults = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kWantFoo, nil];

[defaults registerDefaults:defaultsDefaults];
```

and then after that you get the setting

```
global.gWantFoo = [defaults boolForKey:kWantFoo];
```

This way if the app has not yet set the preference the answer will be `YES` otherwise it will be what the app has previously set it to.

Comment: Hi Paul, wow - thanks for the comprehensive suggestion!  It's given me new perspective to refocus.  I've integrated the clean suggestion of using the const.  Don't know what to tell you mate.. :(, I'm still unable to get this to persist.  I've read boundless tutorials, iOS books, etc.  It's probably my programming techniques which are letting me down here, as clearly the semantics of NSUserDefaults are not rocket science and there's not much to it.  In any case, i'll start a new project just with a switch and try to get this to work. Btw, i've been testing on the simulator mainly. Thanks again

Comment: What are you doing different from what I've said above?

Comment: Only thing i'm doing different is NSMutableDictionary, and just before the init of that, I do global.gWantFoo = YES, to hardcode the default beforehand, which is not unlike '[defaults setBool:YES forKey:PSWantFoo];'.

Comment: Is the posted code up to date? If not can you put your current code. I don't get where `global.globalSettingsDict` comes into it? I has nothing to do with userDefaults. Does that code ever execute? You said you `registerDefaults:`, which means that `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"gSettingsAreSet"];` will never return `nil`

Comment: hi mate, updated code.  I have removed the initial check for whether something is nil or not.  I do however think that I will have to put that check back, as the first hardcode to YES for gWantFoo is always going to win.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the flag @"gSettingsAreSet" after defaults values  are saved

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"gSettingsAreSet"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Hi NeverBe, very good point - I have now implemented your suggestion, thanks!  I was able to save the state of gWantFoo as needed :-)  However, i'm unable to set it back to YES and have it persist - it's like i've just reversed my problem.  Having trouble seeing the wood for the trees at this point..

Comment: you can save gWantFoo same way as gSettingsAreSet